# Google Maps API: InfoWindow at wrong location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My program right now takes input as a message and location, then it will change the map center to that new location and display a message there. Here's the relevant snippet (full code available upon request)

```
function submitPosition(position){
  var messageContent =  $('#message').val();
  var dateTime = new Date();

  var px = position.coords.latitude;
  var py = position.coords.longitude;
  var newLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(px, py);

  db.push({
    author: "Anynomous",
    message: messageContent,
    date: dateTime.toString(),
    location: newLoc
  });
  map.setCenter(newLoc, 5);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<p>" + messageContent + "</p>",
    location: newLoc
  });
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

However, only the map is put at the right center, and the message is off. I don't understand what's really going on.

Comment: try with `infoWindow..setContent :"<p>" + messageContent + "</p>"`, and i never use location, on the info window but put to the `infoWindow.location` or `setLocation`, im not sure.

Comment: Could you put full code to the jsfiddle? So I can check for you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Geolocation to add location, you need add option to your infowindow, like this below :

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
    position: pos,
    content: 'Your Location.'
});
```

try this code snippet in my fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekojs/n1ym9xnw/)

If you need a detail about the options in infowindow, please read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions)..

May be a little help for you..